# Choppy/Jerky Video Performance on MacBook Pro 13" 2016

Tags: macbook-pro, video, performance, adobe-flash

I upgraded from a Late 2013 MacBook Pro 15" to the 2016 13" MacBook Pro. On my old laptop, watching YouTube videos, and PlayStation Vue was smooth. However, on this new laptop, the video is jerky/choppy. For example, if I watch the news and the marque slides at the bottom of the screen, it slides smoothly for a moment, then studders, then smoothly again.

The CPU is not overly active; I'm not running any other programs. I tried using Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, with the the same result. The Internet speed is 75gbs so that's not the issue.

I think I've narrowed it down to Flash videos, however even with iTunes movies purchased from Apple, the video appear to be very low frame rate. For example, scenes that pan a room are not smooth. Perhaps this is just due to the video encoding of iTunes movies.

Since posting this question, I called Apple and they don't think there is a hardware problem. Strangely, on one of my tests with Apple support, I used YouTube to play a 4k video and it appeared very smooth. I cannot tell if YouTube is using the HTML5 native video play in the browser or Flash.

Also, in all cases, the sound is fine in all videos I watched.

The new MacBook Pro has the upgraded i7 processor, and 16GB of RAM and the Iris 550 video chipset.

Should I be getting better performance from this laptop? Is there anything I can do to correct this problem?

Comment: Same issue with my MacBook Pro 13" '15.